# IBDesignable crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS when attempting to call loadNibNamed

Tags: ios, ibdesignable

I have a base class called `DesignableControl`. I use it in my custom views so that I can see them rendered in the storyboard. Here is the base class:

```
public class DesignableControl: UIControl {

    private var view: UIView!

    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configureViewForStoryboard()
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configureViewForStoryboard()
    }

    func configureViewForStoryboard() {
        if let nibView = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType).loadNibNamed("\(self.dynamicType)", owner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView {
            view = nibView
        } else {
            Log("Error loading view for storyboard preview. Couldn't find view named \(self.dynamicType)")
            view = UIView()
        }
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
        backgroundColor = .clearColor()
        addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

Here is my subclass `StackedButton`:

```
class StackedButton: DesignableControl {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    ...
}
```

The code above runs and looks fine when I run the application, however, when I view it in a storyboard, it crashes the Interface Builder process with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the following line in `DesignableControl` (broken out for clarity):

```
func configureViewForStoryboard() {
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    print("bundle: \(bundle)")
    let nibArray = bundle.loadNibNamed("\(self.dynamicType)", owner: self, options: nil)
    print("nibArray: \(nibArray)") //<-- EXC_BAD_ACCESS

    ...
}
```

When I first wrote this code, it used to work, but seems to be broken in the latest version of Xcode (7.2.1 as of this post). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like when running in IB, that `loadNobNamed(...)` is returning a nil. Silly thought, but check that `self.dynamicType` resolves to the same name in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

The code started crashing when run, because the view wasn't getting set up properly. It turns out that the stack overflow issue was a red herring. There was a bug in a subclass in some `@IBDesignable` properties that were accessing `@IBOutlets` before they were set. This was the root problem.

Before:

```
@IBInspectable var text: String? {
    get { return label.text }
    set { label.text = newValue }
}
```

After:

```
@IBInspectable var text: String? {
    get { return label?.text }
    set { label?.text = newValue }
}
```

**Original Answer:**

Stack overflow™!!!

`loadNibNamed()` was calling one of the constructors, which was calling `configureViewForStoryboard()`, which was calling one of the constructors, which was calling `configureViewForStoryboard()`.

I removed the call to `configureViewForStoryboard()` from `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` and it seems to work now.